If this information is in range, yes
I've searched for this but can't seem to find the exact answer.
As an example, I have cells a2:a100 with information on departments, finance dept, marketing, sales, etc.
I'll be listing all departments, past and present, say from cell b2 onwards.
In cell c2, I want there to be a formula to check if the department I put in cell b2 is in the range of a2:a100, and yes or no to be the answer to whichever it is.
Any help appreciated.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I'd like a cell that answers yes if the information from a list matches the information put into the cell next to it. Or answer no if it doesn't.

As I understand your question, you have a list in cells A2:A100.
You have another list beginning in cell B2. You want to check if the values in column B are in the list in column A.
To do this, you can put this formula in C2:
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(XMATCH($B$2:$B$200, $A$2:$A$100))), "Yes", "No")

Edit the range beginning in cell B2 appropriately to cover the list of departments past and future.
